# How to use Google chart API

Tags: android, google-api

I am using a google chart API in [this](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=500x200&chd=e%3aTNTNTNGa&chts=000000,16&chtt=A%20Better%20Web&chl=Hello%7CHi%7Canas%7CExplorer&chco=FF5533,237745,9011D3,335423&chdl=Apple%7CMozilla%7CGoogle%7CMicrosoft)

how can i use this chart in android application?

here is my code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       String url =  "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=500x200&chd=e:TNTNTNGa&chts=000000,16&chtt=A+Better+Web&chl=Hello|Hi|anas|Explorer&chco=FF5533,237745,9011D3,335423&chdl=Apple|Mozilla|Google|Microsoft";
        WebView mCharView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.char_view);
        mCharView.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

and the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView android:id="@+id/char_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:visibility="visible"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Isn't this deprecated now ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to load your chart like @Rajesh said you have to use a webview and than load the url of your chart by:

```
webview.loadUrl(CHART_URL);
```

add to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

but if you are looking how to draw pie chart in android you can see this [tutorial](http://www.artfulbits.com/articles/samples/aicharts/sample-viewer.aspx?sample=piesample) it has sample code attached to

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to draw pie chart in android app without internet

Answer (score 4):

Remember to enable javascript in your webview!

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to display any web content.

```
webview.loadUrl(CHART_URL);
```

Comment: it is not working right it gives me WEb page is not available although the URL iam using is giving me Pie chart in the web browser