# Show Pie chart in Android Application

Tags: android, pie-chart

I want to show pie chart in my android application like below:

[image: Pie chart]

So any one idea about this how can I achieve this? If any library for that then please suggest me.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to show different types of chart,you can use AchartEngine library available in Android or Google charts API [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

Kindly refer to [this](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/) link for more information.there are also several demos available on internet.

You need to do litle bit customisation according to your need. :)

You can ask if you have any furher queries!!

Comment: in Google charts API it show chart  in terms of html code so which way i configure it in my application

Comment: go for Achart engine...Its simple coding in Java

Comment: even i have used same for my application

Comment: What's with the exclamation marks? !! !!

Answer (score 7):

Here are some useful libraries [AchartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/), [AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com/), [charts4j](http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/), [aicharts](http://www.artfulbits.com/products/android/aicharts.aspx), [TeeChart](http://www.steema.com/download/java), [Orson Charts](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/android/index.html), [Holograph Library](http://danielnadeau.blogspot.in/2013/02/holographlibrary-free-open-sourced.html)

Some of these are paid and available as sample demo and some are available for free use. you can use them according to your requirement.

The implementation in the answers will be helpful to you , you can get idea about it through the posts

[Link 0](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/pieTest4.html)

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266543/android-piechart-using-achartengine)

[Link 2](http://jeevanandamkathirvel.blogspot.in/2013/01/android-piechart-implementation-using.html)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043106/android-achartengine-how-to-highlight-particular-chart-element)

[3D Pie Chart](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/09/generate-3d-pie-chart-using-google.html)

Comment: :;Thanks for  your effort and time

Answer (score 4):

You can use Google Charts API which is quite easy to embed

[Google Pie chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

If you want to generate the chart statically on the device you have several third party libraries that can do that for you:

[AchartEngine](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/)

[AndroidPlot](https://androidplot.com/)

[ChartDroid](https://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/)

Comment: To embed Google Charts you can add a WebView to your layout. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814142/how-to-use-google-chart-api

Comment: :Thanks for your effort and time