# half pie chart in android

Tags: android, charts, pie-chart

I want to make a half pie-chart, like the below image,[image]

Is it possible in Android ?

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495302/show-pie-chart-in-android-application

Comment: @vemanna did you got a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

n order to show different types of chart,you can use AchartEngine library available in Android or Google charts API [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

Kindly refer to [this](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/) link for more information.there are also several demos available on internet.

You need to do litle bit customisation according to your need. :)

You can ask if you have any furher queries!!