# how to display pie chart in android

Tags: android, pie-chart

I want to make a **pie chart** in android. I don't know how to make it I have tried the following code for making the **pie chart** but not success.

```
{
"status": true,
"authentication": true,
"message": "Success",
"records": {
    "collection": {
        "target": 0,
        "collection": 0
    },
    "disconnection": {
        "target": 0,
        "collection": 0
    },
    "realisation": {
        "target": 0,
        "collection": 0
    },
    "arrear": {
        "target": 0,
        "collection": 0
    },
    "sanitisation": {
        "target": 0,
        "collection": 0
    },
    "enforcement": {
        "target": 0,
        "collection": 0
    },
    "mr": {
        "target": 0,
        "collection": 0
    },
    "grf": {
        "target": 0,
        "collection": 0
    }
}
}
```

can anybody help me to make a piechart for android

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: What u have tried till now ?

Comment: this video tutorial could be helpful.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWJB1NLFJGg

Answer (score 2):

> In order to show different types of chart,you can use AchartEngine
>   library available in Android or Google charts API [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/)
>
> Kindly refer to this [link](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/) for more information.there are also several
>   demos available on internet.
>
> You need to do litle bit customisation according to your need. :)
>
> You can ask if you have any furher queries!!

[Show Pie chart in Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495302/show-pie-chart-in-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/), which seems to be the defacto default charting library for Android now. It's wildly customisable and relatively easy to use. There's a comprehensive [wiki](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki) and plenty of demos if you're just looking to copy/paste something working into your code.